# Preventing user from modifying their name in Keycloak

Tags: keycloak

In Keycloak, by default, users are able to change their first and last name in the account manager page. However, is it possible to disable this behavior?

Removing both fields in the theme results in those values not being sent and the form failing, and a hand-crafted POST request would defeat this method anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In Keycloak, by default, users are able to change their first and last
> name in the account manager page. Is it possible to disable this
> behavior?

**That can be done out-of-the-box** (since Keycloak 14) by using the [user profile](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/18.0/server_admin/#enabling-the-user-profile) functionality. First, the **preview feature**  `declarative-user-profile` has to be enabled. For that start the server with:

`--features=declarative-user-profile`.

for the Quarkus version, or with

`-Dkeycloak.profile.feature.declarative_user_profile=enabled`

for the Wildfly version.

Bear in mind that:

> Declarative User Profile is Technology Preview and is not fully
> supported.

After starting the server with the aforementioned option, go to the Keycloak Admin Console and:

- Go to the according `Realm`;
- Go to the tab `General`;
- Set `User Profile enabled` to `ON`

[image]

A new tab named `User Profile` (top right) will show up; click on it, and a set of configurable attributes will be shown.

[image]

Click on `firstName`, and then go to `Permissions`

[image]

In that section the permissions can be changed, accordingly. For example, if one sets `Can user edit?` to `OFF`, then when the user tries to change the `firstName` field in the account UI, that UI throws the following warning message:

> The field First name is read only.

The same configuration can also be applied to the `lastName` attribute.

For the new Keycloak UI the workflow is exactly the same as the one I have just described. More information about the feature can be found in the official keycloak documentation ([link](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/#user-profile))

#### UPDATE:

For new keycloak versions use the following env var:

```
- name: KC_FEATURES
  value: 'declarative-user-profile'
```

Comment: Keep in mind that by doing so the fields will also be removed from the registration view, so users might not be able to create accounts anymore.
Therefore in my opinion, this approach is only feasible if you disable user registration.

Comment: @GeorgMoser Thanks for the comment I was unaware of that detail

Comment: @MohammedNoureldin Hi thanks for the edit

Comment: This behavior of read only is not user-friendly. It works, but it is kind of weird. The fields should simple become disabled and uneditable. Not editable and then exception.

Answer (score 6):

I came across a similar problem and after reading this SO post, came to know that although you can disable/hide fields in ftl, you cannot disable form validation

For e.g I hid firstname field , but still cannot submit. Same was the result with disable as well:
[image]

[image]

I am not aware about disabling a particular field in some other way. However there is a workaround in which you can disable the entire account modification flow (Password can still be changed by Forgot Password option).

Bu default, account modification is enabled, but you can disable it for a particular realm by going to Realms -> Clients -> Account.

[image]

The result of this will be, the account page will be inaccessible:

[image]

Comment: We still want to offer all the other features of the account panel, so this solution would be overkill for us… Maybe the only solution would be to fork it?

Comment: This disables the reset password option also. If i try to call the endpoint there is a warning in the logs with "error=client_disabled". I'm using keycloak 10

Comment: @Irxw Probably already late but how about https://stackoverflow.com/a/74913805/1366871

Answer (score 4):

You can remove the client role 'manage_account' for client 'account'.[image]

Comment: Note that this will prevent the account console (both v1 and v2) from functioning altogether. At least with keycloak 21

Answer (score -3):

You can use `readonly` property to disable email you can just change the following line:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" readonly autofocus value="${(account.email!'')}"/>
```